# Python Code For Extracting Duplicates Conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Let's say we have the following dataframe:

```
   group    id  performance
0   exp      A   1
1   exp      B   2
2   exp      B   3
3   exp      C   4
4   control  A   5
5   control  A   6
6   exp      D   7
7   control  D   8
```

What would be the Python code for only extracting the rows such that at least one 'id' exists in **both** 'exp'  and 'control'?

The following is the desired output:

```
   group    id  performance
0   exp      A   1
4   control  A   5
5   control  A   6
6   exp      D   7
7   control  D   8
```

The following code was used for creating this dataframe:

```
students = [('exp', 'A', 1),
            ('exp', 'B', 2),
            ('exp', 'B', 3),
            ('exp', 'C', 4),
            ('control', 'A', 5),
            ('control', 'A', 6),
            ('exp', 'D', 7),
            ('control', 'D', 8)
            ]

import pandas as pd
student_df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['group', 'id', 'performance'])
```

I tried the below code, but it only extracts all the duplicates in 'id' unconditionally. My guess is to add an if statement?

```
student_df[student_df.duplicated(['id'], keep = False)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For efficiency, instead of using lambda and `filter`, use `transform` and boolean indexing:

```
student_df[student_df.groupby('id')['group'].transform('nunique')>1]
```

Output:

```
     group id  performance
0      exp  A            1
4  control  A            5
5  control  A            6
6      exp  D            7
7  control  D            8
```

Timings:

> %timeit student_df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.group.nunique() > 1)
>   5.29 ms ± 165 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> %timeit student_df[student_df.groupby('id')['group'].transform('nunique')>1]
>   3.01 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Base on your sample data column `group` having only 2 values `exp` and `control`:

```
df_out = student_df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: x.group.nunique() > 1)

Out[570]:
     group id  performance
0      exp  A            1
4  control  A            5
5  control  A            6
6      exp  D            7
7  control  D            8
```